# How do I add a super admin, either programmatically or directly through the database or another

Tags: 7, users

```
$new_user = array(
  'name' => 'Sg',
  'mail' => 'sg@email.com',
  'pass' => 'password123',
  'status' => 1,
  'field_custom_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>'S'))), // This becomes $account->field_custom_first_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
  'field_custom_last_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => 'Doe'))),
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'roles' => array(), // No other roles than Authenticated
 //'roles' => array('10' => '10', '11' => '11'), // If you want to specify additional roles, the numbers are role_id's
);
user_save(NULL, $new_user);
```

I've seen this above code but where should I implement this code? I tried adding it and I got the error:

> user_save() is an undefined function.

I just need to be able to login to the system as a super-admin.

Comment: where did you tried to add it? have you tried people > roles ?

Comment: Im sorry I could not login into the admin dashboard so I cant access people>roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. You can use drush to generate a one time login link which allows you to get into the system.

`drush user-login` or its alias `drush uli`

Comment: In fact, you can use `drush uli [username]` to login as any existing user in your website.

Comment: Cheers, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a super admin role`(admin/people/permissions)` and check all the boxes. And then you need to assign this role to the user.

Comment: The question here consists of 2 completely different questions (the last phrase in it is what is the 2nd question). This answer is, IMO, the "best" answer to most of the question, ie as in the title ...